# Show that $f(x) = O(1/x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, asymptotics

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\ge 0$, monotonically decreasing and $\int_0^\infty f(x) \ dx < \infty$. Prove that $f(x) = O(1/x)$.

So basically, both $f(x)$ and $1/x$ are non-negative and monotonically decreasing. We know that $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x} = \infty$ but $\int_0^\infty \lt \infty $ - so there must be some $N$ such that for every $x>N$: $f(x) \le \frac{1}{x}$ which implies $f(x) = O(\frac{1}{x})$.

Is that valid/rigorous enough?

Thanks.

Comment: The "so there must be" step is not really justified -- it the thing it concludes happens to be _true_, but you're going to need a more detailed argument _why_ it needs to be true. For example, exactly how do you use the assumption that $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing? You have to use it _somehow_, otherwise the conclusion isn't true.

Comment: Your conclusion that there is an $N>0$ such that $x>N$ implies $f(x)\le 1/x$ seems to be pulled out of thin air.  Suppose that for all $N>0$ there is an $x>N$ so that $f(x)\ge 1/x$, does this imply $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=\infty$?

Comment: That's a stronger critiera than $O(g(x))$ anyway, to show $f(x) = O(\frac1{x})$, you only need to bound it at $\frac{c}{x}$ for some $c$, doesn't have to be $1$.

Comment: @Barry: True -- but the proof of this case I can imagine right away does start by picking a $c$, and $c=1$ is as good a choice as any. (In fact the assumptions are enough to prove that $f(x)=o(\frac1x)$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $t > 0$,

$$tf(t) = \int_0^{t}f(t)\, dx \le \int_0^t f(x)\, dx \le \int_0^\infty f(x)\, dx.$$

Thus $0 \le f(t) \le M/t$ for all $t > 0$, where $M = \int_0^\infty f(x)\, dx$. So $f(x) = O(1/x)$.